# Loop through a list and save strings to a dictionary

Tags: python, string, loops, dictionary

I have a list of files from a directory that I'd like to modify by removing the ".csv. and seperate the string by the underscore then and add to a dictionary as a key-value pair.  When I set the loop up like this I only get the last key/value in the list, so it seems to be overwriting my data in the list.  What am I doing wrong?

```
filedict = dict()
model = []
fore = []
for f in files:
    nf = f.replace('.csv','')
    model = (nf.split("_")[0])
    fore = (nf.split("_")[1])
    filedict[model] = fore

files =
['MIROC_MAXUSEIS.csv',
 'MIROC_MINALL.csv',
 'MIROC_MINARO.csv',]
```

I want

```
filedict.keys("MIROC", "MIROC", "MIROC") and filedict.values("MAXUSEIS","MINALL","MINARO")
```

Comment: Dictionaries are hashmaps; they are a collection of hashable keys and the values to which those keys "point". "Hashable" means essentially that there is a **unique value** which can represent an object; for instance, the string `"hello"` will always be hashed to the same exact value.

Comment: This means that when you add `"MIROC"` as a key to the dictionary, it will be hashed to whatever its hash value is, and then stored. If you attempt to add the same value as a key again, it will again be hashed to the exact same value, and since that "pointer" already exists in the dictionary, Python thinks you are simply accessing the value associated with that key, hence why it overwrites whatever value was there previously.

Comment: Shorter version: `filedict.keys() == ("MIROC", "MIROC", "MIROC")` is impossible because keys need to be unique.  Maybe you want a list of tuples, rather than a dict?  What are you planning on *doing* with `filedict` after you've built it?  The answer to that question should guide what sort of data structure you build -- if you want to look specific things up according to specific keys, you probably want a dict, but if you just want to iterate over the whole thing, you probably want a list.

Comment: Keys do need to be unique, yes, but that's not actually *enforced* by Python; Python isn't actually stopping the programmer and saying "nope, can't do that, that key already exists". So I think it's helpful to say instead "that's impossible because a dictionary can only store a collection of unique keys. If any key is added twice, the previous value is overwritten."

Comment: A one liner like `pairs = [_.replace('.csv', '').split('_') for _ in files]`, will give you a list of pairs like `[['MIROC', 'MAXUSEIS'], ['MIROC', 'MINALL'], ['MIROC', 'MINARO']]`.

Comment: @accdias `_` is conventionally used when the programmer wants to signify that the value will not be used. You shouldn't ever use `_` if you're actually going to use the value of that variable as it can be confusing to others reading your code, and flies in the face of readability and "self-documenting" code.

Comment: @ddejohn, not really. That is exactly a good use case for the throw away variable.

Comment: lol, no, it isn't. You are literally **not** throwing it away... you are processing it and then using it in a comprehension! This is a terrible use of `_` because to anybody else reading the code, they have no idea what it is. Descriptive variable names are *incredibly* important. A "good" use-case for `_` would be `head, *_ = some_iterable`. Here, it's clear that the rest of the iterable was thrown out and that the programmer does not plan on using it anywhere else in the code.

Comment: Descriptive variables are useful when you are going to use them after that. Since I don't care for the variable inside the comprehension, what is better than throw away name?

Comment: A descriptive variable name would be `[file_name.strip('.csv').split('_') for file_name in files]`. Then, when you come back 8 months later to read your code, you don't need to spend any time figuring out what you were iterating over.

Comment: @accdias see [PEP20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: @ddejohn, see [`PEP620`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0640/), from which I quote the relevant part: _"However, despite the convention, "\_" is not a special variable. The value is still assigned to, the object it refers to is still kept alive until the end of the scope, *and it can still be used*."_  Since I'm just interested in the value and not in the variable name, it seems to me fair use of the `_`.

Comment: lol what? I never said you can't use the value of `_`, I'm saying it's bad practice to do so...

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on tracking both "model" and "fore" separately, use a `list` to track all the `fore` which correspond to a given model:

```py
from collections import defaultdict


model_files = defaultdict(list)


files = ['MIROC_MAXUSEIS.csv', 'MIROC_MINALL.csv', 'MIROC_MINARO.csv', 'BIPOC_HEEBY.csv', 'BIPOC_JEEBY.csv']


for filename in files:
    model, *fore = filename.strip(".csv").split("_")
    model_files[model].extend(fore)
```

Output:

```py
defaultdict(list, {'MIROC': ['MAXUSEIS', 'MINALL', 'MINARO'], 'BIPOC': ['HEEBY', 'JEEBY']})
```